# Angular 2 - Looking for a datagrid

Tags: angular, datagrid

I looking for a table-ui-control in angular 2, but I can't find a good one!

Some features I want from the grid/table:

- Remote data/sorting/filtering
- The filter options in gui should can handle dates/greater then/lower then /equal... and so on
- Infinity scrolling (it should only show/load a few rows and when I scroll it should load some new rows from backend), this should replace the normal paging.

It will be nice if it free or for low budget.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is to wrap a JS DataTable (https://datatables.net/) into a table component. You might have to do a bit of work but you will know how everything works under the covers and you can customize the component to your own internal needs.

I'm an old Flex developer so I often take queues from the Flex api when developing these types of reusable components.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of https://github.com/iainplimmer/ngGridify2

It looks like it has most of the features you are looking for, if you wanted to create an infinity scrolling feature for this that would be fantastic, it's actually not on the road map - but would be a really cool feature!

I'm looking to create an open source grid with an almost zero configuration stage, the ones I found were either buggy or overly complicated.

Iain